# Размытый фон на диве

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Всем доброго дня, вопрос такой интересует(полного ответа в поисковике не нашел). Так вот. Есть слайдер в шапке, на слайдере див с менюшкой и лого, див прозрычный. но нужно сделать махинацию по отношению к картинкам слайдера, что бы див был не просто прозрачным, а и размытым. Как это сделать, дайте совет пожалуйста.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anthonyadamski/pen/yJBpd

Answer (score 0):

Тебе поможет CSS3 filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Если я правильно понял описание.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать фильтры, а-ля [filter: blur(5px)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter), но их использование кушает относительно много ресурсов. Кроме того, это экспериментальная технология - поддержка браузерами в будущем типа не гарантирована.

> **This is an experimental technology**
>
> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the
>   compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the
>   syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change
>   in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.